# How to make a receiver on Android phone?

Tags: android, google-cast

I want to implement an receiver on Android system(android phone/android pad)

I find an app  "CastReceiver" can do this.  so I try to reverse，but the important method its write with c++，on libAirReceiver.so，it's  hard to reverse. I try three days and forgive it.

so, I try to make an app ,step by step. First step, this app register the Googlecast mdns service，but I can't find my devices use chrome on my Mac. but I use “dns-sd -B _googlecast”，it show in the list.
code here:

```
    manager = (NsdManager) getSystemService(Context.NSD_SERVICE);
        String type = "_googlecast._tcp.";
        NsdServiceInfo info = new NsdServiceInfo();
        info.setServiceType(type);
        info.setServiceName("TEST");
        info.setPort(8008);
        String str2 = UUID.randomUUID().toString().replaceAll("-", "");
        info.setAttribute("id", str2);
        info.setAttribute("bs", "C09A71866E39");//MAC
        info.setAttribute("ca", "4101");
        info.setAttribute("cd", str2);
        info.setAttribute("fn", "TEST");
        info.setAttribute("ic", "/setup/icon.png");
        info.setAttribute("md", "Receiver");
        info.setAttribute("nf", "1");
        info.setAttribute("rm", "");
        info.setAttribute("rmodel", "Receiver");
        info.setAttribute("rs", "");
        info.setAttribute("st", "0");
        info.setAttribute("ve", "05");
        manager.registerService(info, PROTOCOL_DNS_SD, getListener());
```

anyone has idea how to build this app? help~

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it helps somehow, libAirReceiver.so works with an AIDL that you can find in same apk:

```
package com.softmedia.receiver.app;

import com.softmedia.receiver.app.AirReceiverAPICallback;

interface AirReceiverAPI {
    void setOpenDialFriendlyName(String name);
    String getOpenDialFriendlyName();
    void setOpenDialEnable(boolean isEnable);
    boolean isOpenDialEnable();

    void setCastFriendlyName(String name);
    String getCastFriendlyName();
    void setCastEnable(boolean isEnable);
    boolean isCastEnable();

    void setRendererFriendlyName(String name);
    String getRendererFriendlyName();
    void setRendererEnable(boolean isEnable);
    boolean isRendererEnable();

    void setAirPlayDeviceName(String name);
    String getAirPlayDeviceName();
    void setAirPlayEnable(boolean isEnable);
    boolean isAirPlayEnable();
    void setAirPlayPassword(String password);
    String getAirPlayPassword();
    boolean isAirplayBlockNewConnection();
    void setAirplayBlockNewConnection(boolean enable);
    boolean isAirPlayConnected();
    boolean isUsingSystemMediaPlayer();

    void setPlaybackPlayerSetting(int playerSetting);
    int  getPlaybackPlayerSetting();

    void setAirMirrorResolution(int resolution);
    int  getAirMirrorResolution();
    void setAirMirrorOrientation(int orientation);
    int  getAirMirrorOrientation();

    void setAirMirrorRecordEnable(boolean isEnable);
    boolean isAirMirrorRecordEnable();
    void setAirMirrorRecordAudioEnable(boolean isEnable);
    boolean isAirMirrorRecordAudioEnable(); 
    void setAirMirrorRecordPath(String path);
    String getAirMirrorRecordPath();

    void setAirTunesAudioLatency(int latency);
    int  getAirTunesAudioLatency();
    void setHideAirTunesUI(boolean isEnable);
    boolean isHideAirTunesUI();

    void setUseMediaCodec(boolean isEnable);
    boolean isUseMediaCodec();  

    void setHideNotification(boolean isEnable);
    boolean isHideNotification();

    void setCallback(AirReceiverAPICallback callback);
}
```

And the callback:

```
package com.softmedia.receiver.app;

interface AirReceiverAPICallback {
    void onCastInvalidSystemTime();
    boolean onCastSessionAccept(String ip);
    void onCastSessionStarted(String ip);
    void onCastSessionEnded();
}
```

I am actually interested on having an implementation working in a multiplatform way, but a trick should be there that I don't know as looking at internet what I saw out there is that a certificate is needed.. And obviously I don't have it..